# How long is the TDZ of a runway?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation, ifr-navigation

How long is the TDZ of a runway?

3000 ft, 3500 ft or 2000 ft?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a question from a test or homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAA defines it so](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-t.html):

> TOUCHDOWN ZONE- The first 3,000 feet of the runway beginning at the threshold. The area is used for determination of Touchdown Zone Elevation in the development of straight-in landing minimums for instrument approaches.

Comment: Unless the runway is less than 3000 feet long…

Comment: @michaelhall I wonder if there are any ILSes on short runways.

Comment: the question isn’t specific to ILS approaches.

Comment: Actually my comment may be N/A.  I checked the local example that first came to mind, ORS:  2901’ runway with an 8% slope and instrument approaches serving each direction.  Both runway 16 & 34 publish the same TDZE although obviously there’s a bit of difference.  So disregard my first comment, but perhaps worth mentioning in the answer?

Comment: Anyway, if the FAA definition doesn’t expand beyond your quote then that’s the answer.  If you acknowledge I will delete my comments to clean this up…